# how to convert List<Map<String, String>> to List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>

Tags: java, java-stream

Can some on tell me how to convert `List<Map<String, String>>` to `List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>`, the key in converted map object of list is one of the value in the map of list.

in short am trying to achieve below . but I am getting null values in list.

````
List<Object> finalStatus = status.stream().map(map->new HashMap<>().put(map.get("testcase_mapping_run_id"), map)).collect(Collectors.toList()); ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `map(map->new HashMap<>().put(map.get("testcase_mapping_run_id"), map))`. That lambda does not return the newly created map. It returns whatever `put` returns, which is [the previous value of the key in the map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-). Since the map was empty, the `map` always returns `null`.

So what you want is probably

```
List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> = status.stream()
    .map(map->{
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> newMap = new HashMap<>();
        newMap.put(map.get("testcase_mapping_run_id"), map);
        return newMap;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```